# Django template tag to determine "a" or "an"

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there an existing django template tag to determine `a/an` before an article? If not, how would I go about writing such a tag?

Comment: @AdamBernier Very cool. Sufficiently answers the question, I think (I mean as an SO "answer").

Comment: @AdamBernier You can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone was kind enough to leave a snippet here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1519/

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice pip package, [anora](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/anora), that will add this template tag for you without having to maintain the code in your own app.

Comment: A bit of a warning that project is more or less dead. So, if you are on Python3 forget it. There is a PR to merge that compatibility but it is from 2015.